# Sum of deep column values in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have this array:

```
Array ( [0] => 
       Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
          [07] => Array ( 
               [2] => 352.9
               [3] => 375737
               [4] => 1000000002
           ) ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
           [07] => Array ( 
               [2] => 362.1
               [3] => 375797
               [4] => 1000000002
        ) ) 
)
Array ( [1] => 
        [0] => Array ( 
           [08] => Array ( 
               [2] => 305.7
               [3] => 375857
               [4] => 1000000002
        ) )
    )
)
```

i need a final array sum for the key 07 ( is the month ) like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 
     Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
              [07] => Array ( 
                   [2] => 3254.9 ( the sum of each 07 )
                   [3] => 6521545 ( the sum )
                   [4] => 98474916521621 ( the sum )
               ) ) 
)
Array ( [1] => 
            [0] => Array ( 
              [08] => Array ( 
                   [2] => 305.7 ( not summed cause month 08 is only one )
                   [3] => 375857 ""
                   [4] => 1000000002 ""
               ) ) 
    )
)
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you show the code with which it's not working? Or do you want us to write it from scratch?

Comment: Are you sure your figures are correct? The sums in 07 seem a little to arbitrary to draw any conclusion.

Comment: i need to write it from scratch!!

Comment: The question does not contain a clear [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try this - I'm sure it's neither a perfect nor optimal solution ( 3 foreach-es ), but it works on a reasonably large data set...

$inputArray is the multidimensional array with the data you provided, btw...

EDIT: Fixed version:

```
$result = array();

foreach( $inputArray as $subArray ) {

    foreach ( $subArray as $subKey => $member ) {

        if ( empty( $result[$subKey]) ) {

            $result[$subKey] = $member;

        } else {
            foreach ( $member as $id => $subMember ) {

                if ( empty( $result[$subKey][$id]) ) {

                    $result[$subKey][$id] = $subMember;

                } else {

                    $result[$subKey][$id] += $subMember;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT2: Since you changed the format of arrays, the solution is different:

Note: $array1 and $array2 are your "global" - predefined arrays.

```
$arrayWrapper = array_merge( ( array ) $array1, ( array ) $array2 );

$result = array();

foreach ( $arrayWrapper as $inputArray ) {

    foreach( $inputArray as $subArray ) {

        foreach ( $subArray as $subKey => $member ) {

            if ( empty( $result[$subKey]) ) {

                $result[$subKey] = $member;

            } else {
                foreach ( $member as $id => $subMember ) {

                    if ( empty( $result[$subKey][$id]) ) {

                        $result[$subKey][$id] = $subMember;

                    } else {

                        $result[$subKey][$id] += $subMember;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested it with your data, should work.

Cheers.

Comment: I have try this, but do not work! i see the same array if i print_r $result!

Comment: Thx! work! I have edited my question adding 2 global arrays! can u fix code for that way? I can't understand how do it!!